# passing jquery ui autocomplete selection into variable

Tags: jquery, variables, select, user-interface, autocomplete

I have a JQuery function to change the color of a button while adding or removing a `href` attribute to it. It works perfectly if I initiate it with blur like

```
$("#name").blur(function() {
        var standards_name = $("#name").val();
        var standards_link = $("#standardslink");
        var update_log = $("#update_log");
        if(jQuery.inArray(standards_name, standards) != -1) {
            if(companyid !== null) {
                standards_link.attr("href", basic_href + "?standards_name=" + standards_name + "&company_id=" + companyid);
            } else {
                standards_link.attr("href", basic_href + "?standards_name=" + standards_name);
            }   
            standards_link.css("color","#2EE52B");
        } else if(standards_name == "") {   
            standards_link.removeAttr("href");
            standards_link.css("color","black");
            update_log.hide();
        } else {
            standards_link.removeAttr("href");
            standards_link.css("color","#FF0011");
            update_log.hide();
        } 
    });
```

but would like it to be initiated on the very selection from the autocomplete drop-down list. This is where I can't get any further. The pasted code works if I manually set the variable "standards_name", e.g. `var standards_name = "xxxx";` but I want the `ui.item.ticker_name` value to be passed to the variable. (The "standards" array and "companyid" are set with `PHP` `json_encode` and passed earlier in the script and works just fine)

Here's the code:

```
$(function() {

        $("#name").autocomplete({
            source: "../autocomplete.php",
            minLength: 2,
            select: function(event, ui) {
            $('#name').val(ui.item.ticker_name);
            $('#mktcap').val(ui.item.mkt_cap);
            var standards_name = ui.item.ticker_name;
            var standards_link = $("#standardslink");
            var update_log = $("#update_log");
            if(jQuery.inArray(standards_name, standards) != -1) {
                if(companyid !== null) {
                    standards_link.attr("href", basic_href + "?standards_name=" + standards_name + "&company_id=" + companyid);
                } else {
                    standards_link.attr("href", basic_href + "?standards_name=" + standards_name);
                }   
                standards_link.css("color","#2EE52B");
            } else if(standards_name == "") {   
                standards_link.removeAttr("href");
                standards_link.css("color","black");
                update_log.hide();
            } else {
                standards_link.removeAttr("href");
                standards_link.css("color","#FF0011");
                update_log.hide();
            } 
            }     

        });
});
```

Answer (score 4):

the most simple solution is to cheat
in the select handler Add

```
$("#name").attr("standards_name",ui.item.ticker_name);
```

and in the first block you can simply

```
  var standards_name = $("#name").attr("standards_name");
```

better yet use jQuery Data function to save the all object :-)

Comment: After like 20 hours of tearing my hair I realized that the ui.item.ticker_name had to be ui.item.value to contain any value in autocomplete. I just assumed it contained a value since the right value got passed to the right textbox, but it was passed automatically no matter if it was undefined or not. So I changed in the autocomplete source and simply triggered the blur event with `$('#name').trigger('blur');` which obvisouly didn't work without it being defined. Since it was nothing you or anyone else could've solved here I'll give you an upvote for trying ;)

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
$("#name").autocomplete({
 source: function (request, response) {
/*Souse code here*/
},
select: function (e, i){
/*Selection code here inorder to get value use i.item.val*/

}
})
```